# CSS bootstrap nav-pills class changing active state

Tags: html, css

following problem: 
I used the Bootstrap class: `.nav-pills`. Which default active state is a different color than i want. (The color for the text.)

```
<div class="pageOne text-center">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="pull-right">
    <a href="#third">Kontakt</a>
  </li></ul></div>
```

I want the active color to be black.(when it is clicked!)
This is all i tried

```
a:active {color:black;}
```

and `.nav-pills a:active {color:black;}`
Thank you =)

Comment: Try using !important to override the default style, so .nav-pills a:active {color:black !important;}

Comment: you have to use `!important`

Comment: on which one?  the .nav-pills a:active or the other?

Comment: this doesnt seem to work on either of them

Comment: @tatanga1888 even in your question it works. What is the issue then?

Comment: you want color only while it is clicked or even after click?

Comment: @Leo the lion It doesnt. I want the active color to be black, which isnt.

Comment: First let me know you want color only on click or even after click you want black color?

Comment: click on this fiddle and you will see black color. https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/wy4ay21q/

Comment: @ Leo the lion oh sorry the second part of your answer was hidden. Just onclick. The other case is fine too, but woulnd't matter because it wont be seen.

Comment: @tatanga1888 did not get you. Check my fiddle. If you will click, it will show black color as soon as you release the click. i can see black color of text but not the black background. You want black background too?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add it like this

```
.nav-pills>li>a:active{
    color:black;
}
```

when you add style this way, it's weight-age increases when browser interprets it compared to default bootstrap style.

Comment: are you mistaking active-state for hover-state(changes color when mouse hovers)

Comment: and please make sure that you have positioned you stylesheet below bootstrap in your 'head' tag